# How to add onclick attribute on the fly?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, appendchild

I have tried below one `el.setAttribute("onclick","alert("+color['R'][i]+")");` but not working in IE older browser.

```
function r_loadResources(color) {
    var rows='';    
    var index =1;
    container = document.getElementById('color_table');
    for(i=0;i<color['R'].length;i++) {  
    if(I%8==0) {
        rows = document.createElement('tr');
        rows.setAttribute("id","row"+i);
        container.appendChild(rows);    
    }
    if(document.getElementById('row'+i))
    rowids = document.getElementById('row'+i);

    var el = document.createElement('td');
    el.bgcolor = color['hex_value'][i]);
    el.setAttribute("height",'20px');
    el.setAttribute("width",'10px');
    el.setAttribute("onclick","alert("+color['R'][i]+")");
    //el.setAttribute("onmouseover","Tip('"+color['color_name'][i]+"');");
    //el.setAttribute("onmouseout","UnTip();");
    rowids.appendChild(el); 
    }
}
```

Html code is `<table><tbody id="color_table"></tbody></table>`

Variables

```
var color = new Array();
color["color_name"]= new Array("Fire Red","Tomato Red","Magenta","Orange","Yellow","Beige Yellow","Kelley Green","Forest Green","Teal Blue","Process Blue","Royal Blue","Navy Blue","Pastel Purple","Osha Purple","Deep Purple","Burgundy","Light Brown","Dark Brown","Beige","Gold","Silver","Dark Grey","Black","White","Blue","Green","Yellow2");
 color["R"]= new Array("195","218","221","231","252","255","0","0","0","0","0","5","129","140","90","110","116","75","238","183","194","114","31","255","0","37","255");
color["G"]= new Array("38","37","19","120","219","252","154","97","153","175","68","44","109","46","26","29","78","51","227","148","193","112","26","255","61","169","198");
color["B"]= new Array("31","29","123","23","0","184","80","47","152","239","129","81","165","126","116","38","42","31","198","65","193","111","23","255","107","55","30");
color["hex_value"]= new Array("#c3261f","#da251d","dd137b","#e77817","#fcdb00","#fffcb8","#009a50","#00612f","#009998","#00AFEF","#004481","#052c51","#816da5","#8c2e7e","#5a1a74","#6e1d26","#744e2a","#4b331f","#ede3c6","#b79441","#c2c2c1","#72706f","#1f1a17","#ffffff","#003d6b","#25a937","#ffc61e");
```

Output should be ![enter image description here][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u1Qx.jpg

Comment: Do not add event handlers with setAttribute!

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: You could just do `if (i % 8 == 0)`

Comment: @epascarello  Nothing added to dom tree..Firefox I can see the color table but IE showing nothing.

Comment: What version of IE, what is the error in the console? append to the tbody and see if that makes a difference. `container = document.getElementById('color_table').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];`

Comment: @epascarello no errors in IE console

Comment: Set the innerHTML of the cell to a whitespace.

Comment: @Teemu this function is called in document onload event. and the output is coming fine in firefox and IE10 too.. problem is showing nothing in older browser

Comment: @epascarello tried whitespace and div tag, nothing worked

Comment: `el.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";` did not work?

Comment: @epascarello   el.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"; is not working

Comment: Your code looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/czY73/show/ in IE8 and IE9 and IE11

Comment: @user2903318 Literally `document.onload`? Try `window.onload` instead.

Comment: @Teemu function is firing is correctly in onload, output only the issue.

Comment: @epascarello  you must choose IE10 Compat View mode in developer toolbar than see your fiddle output

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your help. I found the solution... el.setAttribute("bgcolor","#00000").. should be el.bgcolor ='#00000'

Comment: ideally it would be `el.style.backgroundColor = `

Comment: @epascarello but event is still not firing in older ie.. can you get me a solution

Comment: because you can not add events with setAttribte which is my first comment.

Comment: @epascarello ok give me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is  `var el = document.createElement('td'); el.onclick = el.onclick = new Function("clickHandler('"+color['R'][i]+"')");` It works in all browsers.